# Facebook graph error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, joomla

I want to get all the photos from my page.

The following link is working in facebook graph explorer. But the same url i have pasted in browser but it throwing this error.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/157705150944797/photos/uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You need at least an App Access Token for that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/157705150944797/photos/uploaded?access_token=App-ID|App-Secret
```

Edit: Well, i just tried, for that endpoint it seems that you need a User Token - but it does not have to be an Admin of the Page. If you need a Token that is valid forever, use an Extended Page Token.

You could just use the `/photos` endpoint though, you only need an App Access Token for that one.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Btw, if it still does not work, or works for another Page, there may be an age or country restriction on the Page. In that case, an App Access Token will not be good enough, because you would not be able to identify the User (meaning, his age and country).

Comment: I have used same steps for another account https://graph.facebook.com/772397192827767/photos/uploaded it is working fine.. But I dont know why it is not working.....

Comment: i know one reason, will add it to the answer

Comment: that is not a correct access token - but you should not post a user token anyway. keep your tokens secret.